# make dompdf skip first page when numbering pages with {PAGE_NUM}

Tags: php, html, dompdf

I have the following code below that perfectly adds the page number to each of my pages in the bottom right corner of the document.

I have a header page that DOES NOT need a page number, so would like to skip the number for it.

Is there a way of doing this?  or at the very least modifying the code to be page_num+1, page_count-1, and then div over the header page so that it doesnt show?

```
$dompdf->render();
$canvas = $dompdf->get_canvas();
$font = Font_Metrics::get_font("helvetica", "bold");
$canvas->page_text(522, 770, "Page: {PAGE_NUM} of {PAGE_COUNT}", $font, 10, array(0,0,0));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this using the `page_text()` method since this method applies the specified text on all pages. What you would want to use instead is the `page_script()` method which gives you capabilities similar to dompdf's embedded script, run on all pages.

Since you only need to subtract out the first page you can just subtract one from the current page and page total to get the correct page numbering.

Try the following in dompdf 0.6.2 or earlier:

```
$dompdf->render();
$canvas = $dompdf->get_canvas();
$canvas->page_script('
  if ($PAGE_NUM > 1) {
    $font = Font_Metrics::get_font("helvetica", "bold");
    $current_page = $PAGE_NUM-1;
    $total_pages = $PAGE_COUNT-1;
    $pdf->text(522, 770, "Page: $current_page of $total_pages", $font, 10, array(0,0,0));
  }
');
```

Things are a bit different starting with dompdf 0.7.0:

```
$dompdf->render();
$canvas = $dompdf->getCanvas();
$canvas->page_script('
  if ($PAGE_NUM > 1) {
    $font = $fontMetrics->getFont("helvetica", "bold");
    $current_page = $PAGE_NUM-1;
    $total_pages = $PAGE_COUNT-1;
    $pdf->text(522, 770, "Page: $current_page of $total_pages", $font, 10, array(0,0,0));
  }
');
```

Comment: Something that I found annoying was coding inside a string so an alternative is creating a class with a static method and call it from `page_script` I'll make an example as another answer to this question

Answer (score 1):

This is the same as the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35512037/6438812) but with the help of a class with a static function so that we don't have to code inside a string.

The Class

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use Dompdf\Canvas;
use Dompdf\FontMetrics;

class PdfService
{
    public static function outputPageNumbers(Canvas $pdf, FontMetrics $fontMetrics, $PAGE_NUM, $PAGE_COUNT) {
        if ($PAGE_NUM > 1) {
            $font = $fontMetrics->getFont("helvetica", "bold");
            $current_page = $PAGE_NUM-1;
            $total_pages = $PAGE_COUNT-1;
            $pdf->text(522, 770, "Page: $current_page of $total_pages", $font, 10, array(0,0,0));
        }
    }
}
```

and calling the static function with `page_script`

```php
$dompdf->render();
$canvas = $dompdf->getCanvas();
$canvas->page_script(
    '\App\Services\ProductPdfsService::outputPageNumbers($pdf, $fontMetrics, $PAGE_NUM, $PAGE_COUNT);'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer did not work for me. Why not just check the page number and ignore if first page? Something like this

```
$pdf->page_script ('
if ($PAGE_NUM != 1) {
    $current_page = $PAGE_NUM;
    $pdf->text(550, 750, "Page $current_page", null, 10, array(0,0,0));
 }
```

');